# Magento 1.9 and mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to research how to integrate between magento and mongodb. At first, how to connect? and execute CRUD?

P/s: My system is using mysql, and I want to use mongodb too.

Comment: anybody help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

I based my work with mongo next to magento with this functionality github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo

If you will have problems with connection change _newConnection metod in Mage_Core_Model_Resource to this:

```
protected function _newConnection($type, $config)
{
    if ($config instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element) {
        $config = $config->asArray();
    }
    if (!is_array($config)) {
        return false;
    }

    $connection = false;
    // try to get adapter and create connection
    $className  = $this->_getConnectionAdapterClassName($type);
    if ($className) {
        // define profiler settings
        $config['profiler'] = isset($config['profiler']) && $config['profiler'] != 'false';

        $connection = new $className($config);
        if ($connection instanceof Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface) {
            // run after initialization statements
            if (!empty($config['initStatements'])) {
                $connection->query($config['initStatements']);
            }
        } else {
            $connection = false;
        }
    }

    // try to get connection from type
    if (!$connection) {
        $typeInstance = $this->getConnectionTypeInstance($type);
        $connection = $typeInstance->getConnection($config);
//            if (!$connection instanceof Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface) {
//                $connection = false;
//            }
    }

    return $connection;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi bro, I reference your link and merge it into my project, I also custom mongodb in config.xml, but somethings wrong, I don't check connect mongodb, pls help me.

Comment: First in Cm_Mongo in config.xml you have to configure your mongo connection and then in new module you have to create mongo.xml file in etc folder with schema describing your entities.

Comment: So, how to execute insert, update, delete.. using Cm_Mongo @Marceli Po??

Comment: Well for example if your model class is extending Cm_Mongo_Model_Abstract or your collection is extending Cm_Mongo_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract you can use insert, update ... in the same way like in magento $model = Mage::getModel('your_mdoule/model')->load(id); $model->setSomething(); $model->save();
All this Mongo classes are based on Varien_Object

Comment: Thanks your advice, it's useful for me, I follow your steps and I've a error like that Fatal error: Call to a member function selectCollection() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magentodemo\app\code\community\Cm\Mongo\Model\Resource\Collection\Abstract.php on line 49 Do you any idea??

Comment: What is selectCollection()? If you need to get collection use getCollection() instead

Comment: Yes, I've used getCollection but It references to selectCollection function in Abstract.php you know??

Comment: This function $this->_query = $this->_conn->selectCollection($this->getCollectionName()); in Abstract.php

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the connection layer won't work. You will need a full MongoDB abstraction layer to replace the MySQL abstraction layer plus underlying database.

Take a look at https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo, which should get you started. I haven't used it myself so I cannot vouch for its quality or completeness.

PS: Why do you even want to replace MySQL? Unless you have very good reasons, I'd stay with the default as it be much better battle tested.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I'm not replace mysql, just using mongodb too , for system performance. I'll try this, dear!

Comment: maybe because EAV model used by Magento fits a lot more into a shemaless database like Mongo. It can boost performances on large catalogues

Comment: Might be, might not be especially without sharding. Will also be about the schema design, but practice often showed much less performance gain than theory would have suggested